# which is better for making chart javafx or jfreechart

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, jfreechart, candlestick-chart

I need to make candlestick chart, ohlc chart, xyplot (probably all in different application)

I have tried both jfreechart and javafx chart and is successful in implementing both.

As these charts are from trading perspective and hence they are dynamic in nature.

I liked javafx more than jfreechart....

But I want concrete reasonas to why should I choose javafx over jfreechart.

Has anybody done any research on it.

My application has requirement of plotting some (at max.) 100 point dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: I think this question is not feasible for Q&A because there is no answer for this question.

Comment: *Has anybody done any research on it.* Have **you** done any research on it , yet ?

Comment: "I liked javafx more than jfreechart...." then (if both do what you need) use javafx.

Comment: Try both, pick your poison, use it... Nothing one can do to help here. And it seems you are pretty much decided already

Comment: actually I nee to justify why I want to replace jfree with javafx.

I was just given assignment to do this, but now i even have to justify and I am new to both.

Comment: and @TheNewIdiot
I am not asking for personel experience, I am asking if some one knows about any performance comparison or any such things.

And for Research part, I just started with java, java swing, javaFX. I know programming in c/c++ that too basic. So obviously I am not compatible enough to decide which is good.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**JFreeChart**

- very sophisticated. you can do more stuff in it than in JavaFX.
- API is not easy to understand. You need to put a lot of effort in it to get your charts working like you want to.
- Official Dev Guide and Sample Code, which I'd recommend, are not free.
- Project seems to have stopped being developed ([last changes are more than 2 years old](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/))

**JavaFX**

- Good enough for most usecases.
- Well documented and easy to understand (and completely free)
- In active development (with Mailinglist and Jira).
- Officially supported and featured by Oracle.

Choose your destiny.

Comment: is there performance wise betterment in javafx as compared to jfreechart ???

according to application requirement I mentioned in question.

Comment: my guess is, that JavaFX has a better performance for the things it can do, but this is solely based on assumptions I make on the way JFreeChart and JavaFX are built. I cannot say for sure nor do I think that significant performance comparison tests exist for these two.

Comment: [Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to be sure.

Comment: If you want to use JFreeChart in JavaFX, be sure to check out the FXGraphics2D project. https://github.com/jfree/fxgraphics2d

Comment: Having tried both JavaFX and JFreeChart in a production application, I chose JFreeChart for performance. I was not able to get JavaFX to redraw plots fast enough. I am plotting user simulations in real time as a user adjusts parameters to a mathematical model. Theoretically, JavaFX should be faster since it supports acceleration using the GPU... but the performance problem doesn't seem to be related to graphics, but to the way JavaFX handles changes in data and memory (I also had memory problems when creating a dozen charts or so and redrawing them each time data changed).

Comment: JFreeChart has not stopped to be developed. From [their newsfeed](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/): `5 November 2017: JFreeChart 1.5.0 is now available. This release includes a streamlined build structure with JavaFX support being moved into a separate project (JFreeChart-FX).`